# What is the best way to call an api more than once at the start of a project and save them inside a component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

> This code works fine however it doesn't add the quotes to the quotes component also i'm trying to find a better way for future projects

```
  const fetchData = useCallback(async _ => {
    datas.current.push(await axios.get("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quote/random"))
    return datas;
  }, []); 
  
  let quotes = <SwiperSlide className={SwiperCSS.swiperSlide}>Loading data...</SwiperSlide>;

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(calls < 6){
      if(ref.current){
        fetchData();
      }
    
      return ()=>{
        ref.current = true;
        setCalls(prevCalls => prevCalls + 1);
      }
    }
  })

  if(calls >= 6){
    quotes = datas.current.map((res)=>{
      console.log("QQQ", res.data.quote);
      <SwiperSlide className={SwiperCSS.swiperSlide}> {res.data.quote} </SwiperSlide>
    })

    console.log("Quotes", quotes);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [How to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. The title of your question shouldn't be the question itself. Also please provide more information on what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Instead of lots of API calls why not grab all of the quotes at once and grab a quote randomly from that? And maybe use state.

Comment: @Andy I only need 6 request fetching all of them will be alot

Comment: You can fetch them all with _one_ API call: `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quotes` instead of _six separate_ API calls.

Comment: @Andy Thank you, however i want to know the most efficient way to do it so that if i worked with a huge API i don't have to request the entire data for some data

Comment: But if you were using a different API their criteria for fetching data might be different - in that they might allow you to get a subset of data. At the moment your question is about something that _might_ happen. Note also that your API requests might not be limited to six in this case. If you get a quote you already have in your array you'd have to do another fetch to find another quote, and again if it's the same quote again, so this is hardly efficient.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding my comments here's how I might approach the problem. You'll need to fetch a quote, and check that it's not already in the quotes array. If it's in there make another API call otherwise add it to the array.

When the array is full resolve the array, and add it to state.

```js
function getQuotes() {

  const endpoint = 'https://breakingbadapi.com/api/quote/random';

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    
    // Initialise quotes array
    const quotes = [];
    
    // Initialise the query count
    (async function loop(count = 1) {
      
      console.log(`Fetching quote ${count}`);

      // Fetch the and parse the data
      const response = await fetch(endpoint);
      const data = await response.json();
      
      // `data` is an array of one object so
      // destructure it
      const [obj] = data;

      // Check if the quote exists in the quotes array
      const found = quotes.find(quote => {
        return quote.quote_id === obj.quote_id;
      });
      
      // If it's not there push in the new quote
      if (!found) quotes.push(obj);

      // If the quotes array is not full make
      // another API call, otherwise resolve the
      // quotes array. I've throttled the the API
      // limit to one call per second in this example.
      if (quotes.length < 6) {
        setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++count);
      } else {
        resolve(quotes);
      }
    
    }());
    
  });

}

// Call `getQuotes`, and display the contents
// of the array
async function main() {
  const quotes = await getQuotes();
  console.log(quotes);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let quotes = <SwiperSlide className={SwiperCSS.swiperSlide}>Fetching quotes...</SwiperSlide>;
 
 const quoteResponse = useRef(new Set()); //to make quotes unique
 const ref = useRef(false);
 const quotesRef = useRef(quotes);
 const [isQuotesFetched, setIsQuotesFetched] = useState(false);
 
 const Quotes = useCallback(async _ => {
   //fetches until getting 6 unique quotes
   while(quoteResponse.current.size < 6){
     console.log("fetching");
     quoteResponse.current.add(await axios.get("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quote/random"))
   }

   //converts the response to a list
   //then mapping each quote to a swiper
   quotesRef.current = [...quoteResponse.current].map((res)=>{
     return <SwiperSlide key={res.data[0].quote_id} className={SwiperCSS.swiperSlide}> {res.data[0].quote} </SwiperSlide>
   })

   //Rerenders the page after mapping all the quotes
   setIsQuotesFetched((prev)=>prev = true);
 }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).